# Sharing defines or enums between C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++

Starting to digg into java, coming from c++. I am calling some functions in java from c++ (qt / Android). I miss a way to predefine some tags shareable between both languages avoiding having  to define them twice or using strings.

Something like

> define OPERATION_START   0X01

in c that would be compilable/readable in java.

Does something like this exists or you know some trick to achieve it?

**Edit:** How about something like this:

A java file stuff.java with

> public enum Stuff{
>              Table, Apple, Beach, Eye };

and in Cpp+

> '#define public
>
> '#include "stuff.java"
>
> '#undef public

Would that work? java would enumerate from 0 as does c, right?

Comment: this operation doesn't work because it requires a precompiler but at the moment it can only precompile jsps.

Comment: IMHO, unless you have a serious amount of these declarations, available solutions are going to be worse (much more complex) than copying them over.  Then again, you can always write the declarations in a text file in a custom format and generate both the C++ and Java definitions from that.

Answer (score 2):

You need something that can read one of the definitions and export the other.
There are a bunch of things that can do this.
Two that I know of are:
[SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) and [protocol buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).
SWIG will read the C++ declarations and generate code with the same things in other languages.
Protocol buffers will read some proprietary declaration and generate code for all the languages you need.

There are probably others as well, and I don't know of anything that is lighter weight than those. BTW, those are also good for defining more complex structures that you want to pass between C++ and java (and other languages).

Answer (score 1):

You could model the shared definitions/enumerations in UML or maybe a DSL and use code generation from there to create matching definitions in Java and C++.

Or you could probably also define them in Java classes and build a generator which uses reflection to generate matching C++ headers from that.